# Using slider to slide images and descriptions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a slider that changes the image shown in a modal if a user clicks the left or right button. I would like this slider to also change the description below the image shown in the modal

So for example assuming these are my images and descriptions:

```
['one.jpg','two.jpg']
['some text', 'other text']
```

When image one is show, the text below it should read 'some text'

This is my code:

```
if (this.props.data) {
  const images = this.props.data.images;
  var description = this.props.data.description;
    if (this.props.data.images) {
      var img = images.map((elem, i) => {
        return <div key={i} data-src={elem} />;
      });
      var descr = description.map((elem, i) =>{
        return <div key={i}><p className="modal-description">{elem}</p></div>
      })
    }
  }
}
...
        <AwesomeSlider
          cssModule={[AwesomeSliderStyles, AwesomeSliderStyles2]}
          animation="scaleOutAnimation"
          className="slider-image"
        >
          {img}
        </AwesomeSlider>
      </div>
      <div className="col-md-10 mx-auto">
        <h3 style={{ padding: "5px 5px 0 5px" }}>
          {title}
          {url ? (
            <a
              href={url}
              target="_blank"
              rel="noopener noreferrer"
              className="link-href"
            >
              <i
                className="fas fa-external-link-alt"
                style={{ marginLeft: "10px" }}
              ></i>
            </a>
          ) : null}
        </h3>
        {descr}
```

These are my props:

```
  {
    "title": "Photography",
    "description": [
      "Personal project",
      "test"
    ],
    "images": [
      "p1.jpg",
      "p2.jpg"
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Test",
    "description": [
      "I've learned a lot!",
      "one"
    ],
    "images": [
      "images.jpg",
      "images.jpg"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

With [AwesomeSlider](https://github.com/rcaferati/react-awesome-slider) you can set `onTransitionEnd` function, which does have a `currentIndex` in the event object, you can use this index to update the state through `useState`, this way you can select the active description.

```
const [activeId, setActiveId] = useState(0)
const handleTransitionEnd = e => setActiveId(e.currentIndex)
...

<AwesomeSlider onTransitionEnd={handleTransitionEnd}
...

<div>{description[activeId]}</div>
```